# Динамически изменить script src в Angular

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день.

Имеется код на Ангуляре, который обращается к API некого веб-сервиса (если интересно, платёжная система payon). На одном из этапов обращение к этому API должно выглядеть следующим образом: в HTML требуется вставить тэг `script` с `src` вида `url_api?param={{param_value}}`. Конкретное значение параметра вычисляется контроллером, оно будет при каждом вызове какое-то новое.

Вопрос в том, как поменять src? Попытка решить "в лоб", написав `{{}}`, не работает. Если я правильно понял, Ангуляр рендерит тэги скрипт только один раз, на этапе компиляции (тогда параметр ещё неизвестен). Пока что я написал прямо в контроллере нативный `document.getByElementId`, но это выглядит крайне грубым нарушением MVC. Может, кто-нибудь знает другое решение?

Comment: Вы можете создать директиву, которая будет заниматься созданием тега `script` и изменением `src`. Директивы созданы для работы с **DOM**, поэтому ничего плохого в том, что вы будете использовать в нем нативные функции из `document`, нет. И лучше будет, если Вы в вопросе покажете Ваш код.

Comment: _Попытка решить "в лоб", написав {{}}, не работает_ - добавь код попытки и возможно ошибки из консоли

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт загружается сразу и менять ему src бесполезно.